# ¿Cómo puedo transformar la presentación de los datos en Sql Server?

Tags: sql, pivot

Como podría hacer en SQL SERVER a través de un PIVOT que la informacion en una tabla  asi:

> CURSO          DE  A   DIA         MATERIA
>
> PRIMER GRADO A 7   8   LUNES       RELIGION
>
> PRIMER GRADO A 7   8   MARTES      RELIGION
>
> PRIMER GRADO A 7   8   MIERCOLES   RELIGION
>
> PRIMER GRADO A 7   8   JUEVES      RELIGION
>
> PRIMER GRADO A 7   8   VIERNES     RELIGION
>
> PRIMER GRADO A 8   9   LUNES       MATEMATICA

se muestre asi

> CURSO         DE  A   LUNES       MARTES      MIERCOLES   JUEVES      VIERNES
>
> PRIMER GRADO A 7   8   RELIGION    RELIGION    RELIGION    RELIGION    RELIGION
>
> PRIMER GRADO A 8   9   MATEMATICA

Answer (score 0):

Sin la estructura de tu bd y las tablas que usas o la query que has intentado no puedo dar una respuesta especifica asi que te dejo un ejemplo basico para guiarte de como hacer el pivot:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM CURSOS
 PIVOT
 (
    MAX(MATERIA)
    FOR DIA IN ([LUNES], [MARTES], [MIERCOLES], [JUEVES], [VIERNES])
 ) AS PVT
```

[Ejemplo en SQL Fiddle click para probarlo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f518e/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, utilice la consulta como lo indicas y funciona a la perfección

SELECT *
 FROM ( select curso, dia, materia from CURSOS) t
 PIVOT
 (
    MAX(MATERIA)
    FOR DIA IN ([LUNES], [MARTES], [MIERCOLES], [JUEVES], [VIERNES])
 ) AS PVT